# Issue When Subsetting Data on R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am having an issue with subsetting (using `subset()`) my data set with the objective being to split the dataset into two parts, the first set called "explicit" when there is a variable present in `image_2_id`. The second I want to call "implicit" and have that be the opposite of the latter when there is an `NA` in the `image_2_id` column.

```
selection_id test_id image_1_id image_2_id selection_input  
    1           1      14         12         NA            
    2           2       2         11         NA           
    3           3      18         NA         NA    
    4           4       5          7         NA           
    5           5      11          8         NA         
    6           6      12         NA         NA
```

These are the codes that I created.

```
explicit = subset(selections, image_2_id != "NULL")
implicit = subset(selections, image_2_id = "NULL")
```

When I use the explicit line, it subsets the data exactly how I want it. This issue is with the implicit line, which has either returned 0 or variables or returned the entire dataset depending on the logical argument I was using.

Ideally:

Explicit

```
selection_id test_id image_1_id image_2_id selection_input
 1           1      14         12         NA            
 2           2       2         11         NA
 4           4       5          7         NA           
 5           5      11          8         NA
```

Implicit

```
selection_id test_id image_1_id image_2_id selection_input
 3           3      18         NA         NA 
 6           6      12         NA         NA
```

Comment: `is.na(image_2_id)`

Comment: `"NULL"` is a character value, which is different than `NULL`.  Also, `NULL` is not the same thing as `NA`.  I'd recommend reading up on `is.null` and `is.na`.

Comment: On another note, you'll probably be better off subsetting with `explicit = selections[!is.na(selections$image_2_id), ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is:

```
implicit <- subset(selections, is.na(image_2_id))
```

But why doesn't your current code work? `==` tests for equality not `=` -- and as Benjamin has explained, `NULL` is different from `NA` (which is different from `NaN`, etc.)
 in R.